# IE7 Elements getting media queries

Tags: internet-explorer-7, media-queries

IE7 is scanning all of the styles in my css regardless of whether or not they're in a media query.  I thought IE7/8 ignores media queries.  It's not ignoring them, it's just barreling through and grabbing all of the styles.  Very strange.

I've tried to search for a solution, but all I can find is ways to hack it so media queries actually work in IE7.

Would the best way be to just create a separate css file for the media queries that doesn't load in IE7?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to edit your question than add comment with another...

Comment: Are you running in Quirks Mode, where it's using a combination of IE 7 and 8 to render the page? That may be causing issues.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how/why that may be causing issues?

Answer (score 0):

There are JS libraries to make IE support CSS3 media queries:

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Comment: Question was about how to stop IE 7 applying mq styles, not about making them work. Author was aware of the poly-fills. -1

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. IE7 does not ignore media queries, so there's two solutions I've thought of, though I wish there was a more elegant solution:

1) Put all queries at the top of the page, so the last default appearance will take precedence. Unfortunately, if you're overriding the styles according to, for example, screen size, then you have to put the media queries at the bottom.

2) Reset the styles in IE7 with an IE-specific stylesheet (loaded after your main stylesheet). The method I've been using for this is taken from Boilerplate (specifically the Boilerplate theme in Wordpress here: http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/boilerplate):

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="no-js ie ie6 lte7 lte8 lte9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="no-js ie ie7 lte7 lte8 lte9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="no-js ie ie8 lte8 lte9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="no-js ie ie9 lte9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
```

This enables you to target IE browsers, and you could put the styles in its own stylesheet (so other browsers aren't loading it at all) or at the end of your normal stylesheet.

```
html.ie7 div {}
```

Etc.

Neither method is very graceful... This crap is why I hate Internet Explorer. (Would you believe my site still gets visits from IE7 and IE6 users? Too bad for the IE6 users, but I'm not even bothering with checking compatibility for them anymore.)